# rethinkdb/memsql export table record on trigger to a postgresql table

Tags: postgresql, export, rethinkdb, eventtrigger, singlestore

Is it possible to create a trigger to export a table record from rethinkdb/memsql to a postgresql table, or what might be a proper solution to the latter?

The objective to this is to transfer tuples once they have been fully populated to another database as fast and reliable as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use changefeeds, listen for new records inserting/updating and flush it to postgresql.

Say you can do this in NodeJS:

```
var r = require('rethinkdb')

r.connect()
  .then(function(conn) {
    return r.table('user')
      .changes()('new_val')
      .run(conn)
  })
  .then(function(cursor) {
    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
      //do somethng with this document, such as writing it to a table in postgresql
      console.log(doc)
    })
  })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I was also thinking about using rethinkdb and rabbitmq for this, but actually this look pretty great. I'll try your solution.

Comment: Do you know a solution for memsql?